# If statement to check if first character is a number

Tags: php

I need a php if statement to check if the first character of a string is a number but I'm not sure how to do it, I've tried a couple of things that haven't worked. The basic code I have is below, where it says "a number" is where I need it to ckeck the first character.

```
if ($row['left_button_link'] == a number) 
{
printf('hello');
}

else 
{
printf('bye bye');
}
```

Also how do I add a third check to this statement. The if is checking for a number, the else strings will begin with "/" but if I wanted a third option if the string is empty, no characters at all, how do I add that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)?

Comment: This stuff (particularly the last request) is very basic - I would suggest you follow through an online PHP tutorial. There are many about, but 2 are: http://www.w3schools.com/php/ & http://www.tizag.com/phpT/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are built-in functions for doing what you need.

- `is_numeric()` to check if is a number,
- `substr()` or similr for checking if the first character is something
- `empty()` for checking if a string is empty

Checking if it is a number:

```
if( is_numeric(substr($string,0, 1))  ){

echo "it is a number";

}
```

As N.B commented below, you can treat strings as arrays, and this should also work:

```
if( is_numeric($string[0]) ) {

    echo "it is a number";

}
```

---

So, when we apply all these, your code should look like:

```
$var = $row['left_button_link'];

if( is_numeric($var[0]) ) 
{
    echo "It starts with a number!";
}
elseif ( $var[0] == '/' )
{
    echo "Uh oh, first character is a slash";
}
elseif( empty($var) ) {
    echo "Bye bye";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just a note - you can treat a string as an array of characters and use `$string[0]` instead of substr. +1 in any case.

Comment: @user2574794 FYI, the rest of the question is answered further down in my answer

Comment: @user2574794: I've added a complete example above :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Last bit of code is extremely wrong

Comment: @AmalMurali better lol

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: That was the result of a quick edit. Corrected :P

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function:

```
is_numeric($str[0])
```

So the final product should be:

```
if (is_numeric($row['left_button_link'][0])) {  // check if first char is numeric
    printf('hello');
}
elseif ($row['left_button_link'][0] == '/') {   // check if first char is '/'
    printf('First char is /');
}
elseif (empty($row['left_button_link'])) {      // check if string is empty
    printf('Empty!');
}
else{
    printf('bye bye');
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the elseif should be checking first character is a `/`

Comment: What is wrong with this answer, so that I can improve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
is_numeric(substr($string, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_numeric(substr($row['left_button_link'], 0, 1))){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
if(preg_match('/^\d/,$input)) {
    echo "First char is a digit.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For question a `use is_numeric()` for question b use `elseif (...)`

```
if (is_numeric($row['left_button_link'][0])) {
    printf('hello');
    }
elseif (empty($row['left_button_link'])){
    printf('String is empty');
    }
else{
    printf('bye bye');
    }
```

HTH
(though seriously for a question this simple you should look it up in the manual)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the elseif should be checking first character is a `/`

Comment: According to the OP: " but if I wanted a third option if the string is empty, no characters at all, how do I add that?"

Comment: yes, and that check is your 2nd option, not your 3rd

Comment: yes but OP "the else strings will begin with "/"". and empty testing is quicker than specific value checking (at least it is in Python - now that I say this I realize I haven't actually tested with PHP)

Comment: Speed has no relevance when the two methods produce different results

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ctype_digit($row['left_button_link'][0]))
{
    //First char is numeric
}
else if($row['left_button_link'][0] == '/')
{
    //First char is "/"
}
else if(trim($row['left_button_link']) == '')
{
    //String is completely empty
}
else
{
    //Something else
}
```

Be careful when using `empty()` to check if a string is empty - it can only be reliably used on arrays. `empty()` will return false when passed ' ' - it's more reliable to compare the output of `trim()` with ''

Comment: People answer so quickly here I didn't see this! So "else if" is how to have multiple ifs. Thank you, this is exactly want I needed :)

Comment: @user2574794 Indeed, and remember to take note of my final sentence about `empty()` it will NOT class a string with a space in it as empty

Comment: @user2574794 As this is technically the correct answer for the whole question (though other people provided valid partial answers) I would also suggest removing the tick from the other answer and accepting this answer instead, for future readers of this question